# Scrollbar preview disappearing when redrawing items onto highstock

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highstock by highsoft (http://highslide.com/).

I'm trying to allow users to change the chart type (spline, line, areaspline, etc). I'm doing this by resetting the options, popping the items out of the series and re-adding them to the series. It works well except the scroll bar preview disappears when re-adding everything. Any help would be great appreciated. Here's my code:

```
    createChart: function(seriesOptions){
        var cmp        = this;
        var chart_type = this.collection.chart_type;
        if(!chart_type){
            chart_type="line";
        }   
        if(!cmp.chart){
            var options = { 
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'preview',
                    type: chart_type,
                    zoomType: 'x' 
                },  

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 4
                },  
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function() {
                                    console.log(this.config[0]);
                                }   
                            }   
                        }   
                    }   
                },  
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                    yDecimals: 2
                },  
                series: seriesOptions
            };  
            cmp.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        }else{
            while(cmp.chart.series.length>0){
                cmp.chart.series[0].remove();
            }   
            if(cmp.collection.compare_type=='percent'){
                cmp.chart.options.plotOptions.series.compare = 'percent';
                cmp.chart.options.tooltip.pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>';
            }else{
                cmp.chart.options.plotOptions.series.compare = undefined;
                cmp.chart.options.tooltip.pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>';
            }   

           _.each(seriesOptions, function(option){
               option.type = cmp.collection.chart_type;
               cmp.chart.addSeries(option, true, false);
           }); 
            cmp.chart.redraw();
           //window.chart = cmp.chart;
        }   
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out...

I realized that "navigator" becomes one of the series items and i removed it in the while loop. So now I just gotta pop off all items in the series whose name is not "navigator".